# How can I fix the if statements in my while loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

In the `if` statements of my `while` loops, I want it to loop back to ask for the company name when the user sets `verify_name` to no. However, if the user inputs sets `verify_name` to no, it re-loops to the `verify_name` input. How can I fix this so that it breaks out of this loop and re-ask the company name?

```
import time
while True:
    company_name = input("\nWhat is the name of your company? ")
    while True:
        verify_name = input("\nPlease verify that {} is the correct name of your company \nusing Yes or No: ".format(company_name))
        if verify_name.lower() == "no":
            print("\nPlease re-enter your company name.")
            continue
        elif verify_name.lower() not in ('yes', 'y'):
            print("\nThis is an invalid response, please try again.")
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        else:
            print("\nWelcome {}.".format(company_name))
            break
    else:
        continue

    break
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the decision to re-ask the company name *outside* of the nested `while` loop; the inner `while` loop should *only* be concerned with validating the yes/no input.

```
while True:
    company_name = input("\nWhat is the name of your company? ")

    while True:
        verify_name = input("\nPlease verify that {} is the correct name of your company \nusing Yes or No: ".format(company_name))
        verify_name = verify_name.lower()
        if verify_name not in {'yes', 'no', 'y', 'n'}:
            print("\nThis is an invalid response, please try again.")
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        break

    if verify_name in {'y', 'yes'}:
        print("\nWelcome {}.".format(company_name))
        break

    else:
        print("\nPlease re-enter your company name.")
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `else` after `verify_name in {'y', 'yes'}:`. If the user enters a valid company name, you immediately break from the loop. So if `print("\nPlease re-enter your company name.") ` was put at the end of the loop without the `else`, it would still only be run when they didn't enter `yes/y`.

Comment: @ChristianDean: sure, you can omit the `else:` indentation; I'm just being explicit. The resulting bytecode is the same either way.